# xrandr fails on dock with multiple monitors

Tags: linux, xrandr, multi-monitor

EDIT: added some stuff that solves the issue at the end of the question - it's based on what Robert Siemer suggested, so he's answer is marked as correct

When I cold-plug my Lenovo USB-C dock on my laptop I get my 2 additonal monitors working (3 total).

When hot-plugging the dock, though, I get the following error from `arandr`:

```
XRandR returned error code 1:
X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request: 140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request: 21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
Serial number of failed request: 44
Current serial number in output stream: 44
```

```
  1920x1080 (0x48) 142.600MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1936 end 1952 total 2080 skew    0 clock  68.56KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1142           clock  60.03Hz
  1920x1080 (0x56f) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
```

Additionally, when working with all 3 monitors, often at some point the laptop screen will freeze applications randomly, so I often disable the laptop screen to avoid that.

My laptop is a Lenovo X1 carbon 8th gen. I'm on Manjaro Linux, fully updated, using i3 with X11, not Wayland.

What follows is the shortened output of `xrandr --verbose`

1. when the monitors are not connected I get:

```
xrandr --verbose | grep -E '^[^[:space:]]|curr|pref' | sed -e 's/(norm.*)//' 

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 6535 x 2434, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1256+1354 (0x48) normal  310mm x 170mm
  1920x1080 (0x48) 142.600MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
DP1 disconnected 
DP1-1 connected 
  1440x900 (0x78b) 106.500MHz +HSync -VSync +preferred
DP1-2 connected 
  1920x1080 (0x56f) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync +preferred
DP1-3 disconnected 
DP2 disconnected 
HDMI1 disconnected 
VIRTUAL1 disconnected
```

2. with dock connected and restart (i.e. everything okay) I get:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4740 x 3600, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+2820+2520 (0x4b) normal  310mm x 170mm
  1920x1080 (0x4b) 142.600MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
DP1 disconnected 
DP1-1 connected 900x1440+0+0 (0x4c) right  410mm x 260mm
  1440x900 (0x4c) 106.500MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
DP1-2 connected 1920x1080+900+1440 (0x4d) normal  530mm x 300mm
  1920x1080 (0x4d) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
DP1-3 disconnected 
DP2 disconnected 
HDMI1 disconnected 
VIRTUAL1 disconnected
```

Answer:

Ok! so by avoiding arandr entirely and first using:

```
xrandr --output DP1-2 --auto 
xrandr --output DP1-1 --auto
```

makes the two external monitors work when hot-plugging.

then I can use:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2820x2520 --rotate normal --output DP1 --off --output DP1-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 0x0 --rotate right --output DP1-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 900x1440 --rotate normal
```

to set up them up. Before, by just putting the above in a script did not work, but by inclued the --auto for the two screens in the script then it works also when hot-plugging:

```
xrandr --output DP1-2 --auto 
xrandr --output DP1-1 --auto  

xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2820x2520 --rotate normal --output DP1 --off --output DP1-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 0x0 --rotate right --output DP1-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 900x1440 --rotate normal
```

however, if I don't run the setup (each separately) with arandr --auto, they fail.

Nothing changes in dmesg when doing these steps, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message does not reveal which `xrandr` command `arandr` launched (and with what intentions).

I have to do some assumptions here. I encourage you to confirm/deny them with your input. So here is what I assume:

- when booted with the dock, all monitors work
- when the dock is hot-plugged, only the internal monitor continues displaying, the external monitors stay black/off
- the wrapper you use is `arandr` (which I don’t know myself and is best left out of the picture while investigating the problem!)
- you and `arandr` want to switch the external monitors on

I would launch:

```
xrandr --output DP1-1 --auto
```

and then

```
xrandr --output DP1-2 --auto
```

What happens?

I further guess that `arandr` is doing something similar and that these commands unfortunately do not work. You did not include new output of the kernel (revealed with two invocations of `dmesg`, before and after any `xrandr` command; only report new messages, if any).

If that does not work, start driving the monitors with lower resolutions, one by one. E.g.:

```
xrandr --output DP1-1 --mode 800x600
```

Works?

What I do know is:

- it is not a pixel clock issue: cold-plugging the monitors works with all different modelines and frequencies; a pixel clock shortage would not support that
- your output with the monitors connected looks more like “with the monitors switched off”, because they are reported as connected; was that the situation  even without the dock? (Or with the dock, but the monitor cables removed?)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that this command fails in the hot-plug case?

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2820x2520 --rotate normal \
    --output DP1 --off \
    --output DP1-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 0x0 --rotate right \
    --output DP1-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 900x1440 --rotate normal
```

That still leave the question open of why it does not work.

Could you hot-plug and execute these one by one and say which one fails?

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 2820x2520
xrandr --output DP1-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 0x0 --rotate right
xrandr --output DP1-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 900x1440
xrandr --output DP1 --off
```

By the way, do I see it right that you have the three monitors diagonally touching each other on one corner only?